How do I take the output from R and store each piece of output into a separate column?
I am using the function "preventr" in RStudio. It basically is an equation that uses around 10 parameters to predict cardiovascular disease risk for patients. I have a dataframe with >50,000 observations with each row representing a unique patient and their unique parameters (all the parameters necessary for the risk modeling). I want to calculate their cardiovascular disease risk by using the preventr package (specifically, the function: estimate_risk). How do I save the output (which comes in the form of a tibble) into new columns for each participant in the original data frame that contains all the parameters needed to estimate the risk? Please note that the estimate_risk function output is a tibble that contains multiple risk predictions, and I want to save each risk prediction in a separate unique column. Please refer to the code and output below.
df1:

install.packages("preventr")
library(preventr)
estimate_risk(
  age = df1$AGE,
  sex = df1$SEX,
  sbp = df1$SystolicBPAvg,
  bp_tx = df1$AnyAntihypertensive,
  total_c = df1$TCHOL,
  hdl_c = df1$HDL,
  statin = df1$AnticholesterolDrug,
  dm = df1$Diabetes,
  smoking = df1$CurrentSmoking,
  egfr = df1$eGFR,
  bmi = df1$BMI,
  hba1c = df1$A1c,
  uacr = df1$UACR,
)

#Example input#:
estimate_risk(
  age = 54,
  sex = "female",
  sbp = 151,
  bp_tx = TRUE,
  total_c = 197,
  hdl_c = 47,
  statin = FALSE,
  dm = FALSE,
  smoking = TRUE,
  egfr = 88,
  bmi = 32,
  hba1c = 6.2,
  uacr = 70,
)

#Example output#:
$risk_est_10yr
# A tibble: 1 × 8
  total_cvd ascvd heart_failure   chd stroke model over_years input_problems
      <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>      <int> <chr>         
1     0.138 0.076         0.067 0.036  0.044 full          10 NA            

$risk_est_30yr
# A tibble: 1 × 8
  total_cvd ascvd heart_failure   chd stroke model over_years input_problems
      <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>      <int> <chr>         
1     0.447 0.269         0.295 0.145  0.163 full          30 NA            



I want to be able to save the output for total_cvd risk, ascvd risk, heart_failure risk, chd risk, stroke risk for both the 10yr estimate and the 30yr estimate. For example, columns as follows: total_cvd_10yr, ascvd_10yr, heart_failure_10yr, chd_10yr, stroke_10yr, total_cvd_30yr, ascvd_30yr, heart_failure_30yr, chd_30yr, and stroke_30yr.
I would be most grateful for your help. Please let me know if you need additional information. Thank you!!

Please provide data, you didn't specify df1, therefore we can't reproduce your code.

The output of estimate_risk() is a list with two elements, named "risk_est_10yr" and "risk_est_30yr".
purrr::list_rbind() combines elements into a data frame by row-binding them together. Then we can remove the "risk_est_" part of the two output names to make the final column names more concise. And then we can reshape wide using the combination of the "time" column and each of the variable columns.
library(tidyverse)
est1 |>
  list_rbind(names_to = "time") |>
  mutate(time = str_remove(time, "risk_est_")) |> # optional
  pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = 2:9, names_vary = "slowest")
  

Result
  total_cvd_10yr ascvd_10yr heart_failure_10yr chd_10yr stroke_10yr model_10yr over_years_10yr input_problems_10yr total_cvd_30yr ascvd_30yr heart_failure_30yr chd_30yr stroke_30yr model_30yr over_years_30yr input_problems_30yr
           <dbl>      <dbl>              <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>                <int> <chr>                        <dbl>      <dbl>              <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>                <int> <chr>              
1          0.138      0.076              0.067    0.036       0.044 full                    10 NA                           0.447      0.269              0.295    0.145       0.163 full                    30 NA      

Using
est1 <- preventr::estimate_risk(
  age = 54,
  sex = "female",
  sbp = 151,
  bp_tx = TRUE,
  total_c = 197,
  hdl_c = 47,
  statin = FALSE,
  dm = FALSE,
  smoking = TRUE,
  egfr = 88,
  bmi = 32,
  hba1c = 6.2,
  uacr = 70,
) 

